# ESP32 with Flask server to display data in web

Tags: python, flask, arduino, esp32

`I'm attempting to send data from an ESP32 to a Flask application on my PC for real-time visualization. I've followed tutorials and reviewed the codes, yet I'm still encountering a 'connection refused' error on the ESP32. I've double-checked IP addresses and ports, and I'm confident they match. Any insights into why this issue might be occurring?

**app.py code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')

# Almacena los datos recibidos del ESP32
data = {'gasto': [], 'presion': [], 'vibracion': []}


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    try:
        content = request.get_json()

        gasto = content['gasto']
        presion = content['presion']
        vibracion = content['vibracion']

        data['gasto'].append(gasto)
        data['presion'].append(presion)
        data['vibracion'].append(vibracion)

        print(f"Received data: gasto={gasto}, presion={presion}, vibracion={vibracion}")
        return jsonify({'success': True})
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error receiving data: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({'success': False, 'error': str(e)})


@app.route('/get_data')
def get_data():
    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

esp32 code

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "ASUS_F4";       // Nombre de tu red Wi-Fi
const char* password = "banana_6424"; // Contraseña de tu red Wi-Fi
const char* serverAddress = "http://192.168.50.177:5000/data"; // Cambia la dirección IP con la de tu PC

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void loop() {
  float gasto = 123.45; // Valor simulado de gasto
  float presion = 67.89; // Valor simulado de presión
  float vibracion = 0.12; // Valor simulado de vibración

  // Crea un objeto JSON
  DynamicJsonDocument jsonDoc(200);
  jsonDoc["gasto"] = gasto;
  jsonDoc["presion"] = presion;
  jsonDoc["vibracion"] = vibracion;

  // Serializa el JSON en una cadena
  String payload;
  serializeJson(jsonDoc, payload);

  // Crea una instancia de HTTPClient
  HTTPClient http;
 Serial.println("Server Address: " + String(serverAddress));
  // Envía la solicitud POST al servidor
  http.begin(serverAddress);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(payload);

  if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
    Serial.printf("HTTP Response code: %d\n", httpResponseCode);
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(response);
  } else {
    Serial.printf("HTTP Request failed: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpResponseCode).c_str());
  }

  http.end();

  delay(5000); // Espera 5 segundos antes de enviar el siguiente dato
}
```

Thxs

Monitoring a system and display data on a website`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try:

- Make sure that the ESP32 is connected to the same network where the Flask server is running.
- Try to communicate with the server using the browser, or curl / Postman to send the exact same request that the ESP32 would send. Ideally you can try doing this from a different computer connected to the same network. If this doesn't work, then you know the problem isn't on the ESP32 side.